# Can't remove interface from zone with NetworkManager enabled. - Firewalld / Centos8

Tags: linux, centos, firewalld

My issue is when I'm trying to remove interface from public (default) zone  I get error:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-interface=eth0 --permanent`

```
The interface is under control of NetworkManager and already bound to the default zone.

The interface is under control of NetworkManager, setting zone to default.

success
```

Public zone configuration:

```
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: eth0
sources: 
services: 
ports: 
protocols: 
masquerade: no
forward-ports: 
source-ports: 
icmp-blocks: 
rich rules: `
```

When I am stopping the NetworkManager it allows me to remove it. However when I start NetworkManager back again and restart firewalld the interface eth0 is back in public zone.

Comment: In theory you fix this by `nmcli connection modify eth0 connection.zone work` (or whatever zone to put it in)

Comment: same problem here, nmcli command of @aredridel sadly didn't work...

Comment: Just in case: something like `firewall-cmd --change-interface=lxcbr0 --zone=lxc --permanent` it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Run into this several times before, `nmcli` does not want to let you remove an interface from a zone. What it will allow is for you to move it -

```
nmcli con mod blah connection.zone internal
```

which at least gets it out of the zone you want to leave.

Then you can either turn down the interface with nmcli or go right to

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-emx
```

and toggle

```
ONBOOT=no
```

and completely remove the line

```
ZONE=whatev
```

then its -

```
systemctl restart network
```

and voila, its gone from the firewall and nmcli doesn't care what happened.

This is for old guys used to the good old days of CentOS 4 & 5..
I'm thinking there is probably a way to do it all in nmcli but I haven't figured it out yet, maybe some other learned individual could advise.

.